# write XML value on the server with c#

Tags: c#, xml

I'm tryng to update a value into tag on a xml file,i use:

```
xmlDoc.Save((URLString));
```

In local it's work,but if i read file from a serve,i get error "URI not possible".
The file and folder permission on server have setting 777.

Comment: You can't write/update on remote machine where you don't have permission. Do you have write permission?

Comment: yes,that my server.i've permission and set permission to folder and file to 777.

Comment: Is this when reading or writing? "URI not possible" sounds like the path to the file is misspelled or misconstructed. If you use the same path in another way (e.g. from a webbrowser) does it work?

Comment: yes works,the error on the program is "URI format not supported".

Comment: What do the contents of URLString look like? ftp:\\hostname\..., \\hostname\..., something else?

Comment: like as `"http://site.tld/folder"`

Comment: You're not going to be able to save a file at an http location. Can you access as ftp instead?