# change XML innertext value on server with c#

Tags: c#, xml, innertext

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [write XML value on the server with c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8456094/write-xml-value-on-the-server-with-c-sharp)

i've an xml file loaded on a webfolder,this file contains a tag:

```
<mytag>yes</mytag>
```

I've try to change tag content "yes" to no via c# and little form with 2 button.

In local its works fine,but if file is loaded on a server,i'm able to read,but not able to write because

```
xmlDocument.Save(myUrl); dont works in uri.
```

I've try to find solution on web,but didn't found.

Application is on windows.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot save any file at http without server app capability to save the posted data.